# Update list column data via HTML form web part

Tags: client-object-model

I'm trying to update list data on Sharepoint via HTML web part. This is my update function:

```
  function UpdateListItems( ids ) {

    var response = getNode( 
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
        '<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">' +
        '<soap12:Body>' +
           '<UpdateListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">' +
                  '<listName>' + wikiLibrary + '</listName>' +
                  '<updates>' +
                     '<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1">' 
                        + ids +
                     '</Batch>' +
                  '</updates>' +
               '</UpdateListItems>' +
        '</soap12:Body>' +
        '</soap12:Envelope>'
        );
 alert( response.xml );
```

}

This results into this error:

0x8102000aInvalid URL Parameter. The URL provided containes an invalid Command or Value. Please check URL again

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Include **Method** and **Field** command inside batch command.

below is example,

```
 function UpdateListItems( ids ) {

var response = getNode( 
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
    '<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">' +
    '<soap12:Body>' +
       '<UpdateListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">' +
              '<listName>' + wikiLibrary + '</listName>' +
              '<updates>' +
                 '<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1">' 
                  '<Method ID='+ ids + 'Cmd="Update">'+
                     '<Field Name="ID" >'+ids+'</Field>'+
                   ' </Method> '+
                 '</Batch>' +
              '</updates>' +
           '</UpdateListItems>' +
    '</soap12:Body>' +
    '</soap12:Envelope>'
    );
```

alert( response.xml );

Refer [this](http://dotnetstep.blogspot.com/2009/01/batch-update-in-sharepoint.html) for batch commands.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was solved by targeting list items in getListItems function -

```
               k++;
               batchstring = batchstring + '<Method ID="' + k + '" Cmd="Update">';
               batchstring = batchstring + '<Field Name="ID">' + data.childNodes[i].attributes[j].value + '</Field>';
               batchstring = batchstring + '<Field Name="Date">' + dag + '</Field></Method>';
```

the `batchstring = batchstring + '<Field Name="ID">' + data.childNodes[i].attributes[j].value + '</Field>';` was changed from `batchstring = batchstring + '<Field Name="ows_ID">' + data.childNodes[i].attributes[j].value + '</Field>';`